# How to tally votes from the item selected from combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

the user chooses his/her candidate from the Combobox and when the button "vote" is clicked a tally of votes will be shown in Textboxes. my code doesn't work and I don't know why. here is my code:

```
void BtnVoteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I already added the items from the properties tab
    if (comboxCandidate.SelectedItem == "VAL") 
    {
        int ctrVal = 0;
        ctrVal += 1;
        tbVal.Text = ctrVal.ToString();
    }

   if (comboxCandidate.SelectedItem == "LESTER")
   {
        int ctrLester = 0;
        ctrLester +=1;
        tbLester.Text = ctrLester.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger to be sure that you are going through the `if` blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say why it doesn't exactly work, but looking at your code then you have this:

```
int ctrVal = 0;
ctrVal += 1;
...
int ctrLester = 0;
ctrLester +=1;
```

Here you are creating a new variable called ctrVal/ctrLester within your if statement each time it is executed, and then incrementing it.  So the value will only ever be 1.  And each time you click on your button the variable is newly initialised.

You need to move the declaration and initialisation of your variables to the class level if you want to keep a global count.

So that you have something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int ctrVal = 0;
    int ctrLester = 0;
...

void BtnVoteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (comboxCandidate.SelectedItem.Equals("VAL"))
     {
        ctrVal += 1;
        tbVal.Text = ctrVal.ToString();
     } 
     else if (comboxCandidate.SelectedItem.Equals("LESTER"))
     {
        ctrLester +=1;
        tbLester.Text = ctrLester.ToString();
     }
 }
```

PS:  You should also use equals to compare strings, so I updated that.